# Unknown program 'spark-itemsimilarity' chosen

Tags: apache-spark, apache-mahout, recommender-system

I have cloudera CDH5 running inside a virtual box.

when I try to run :

```
mahout spark-itemsimilarity ....
```

I get the error:

```
Unknown program 'spark-itemsimilarity' chosen.
```

Do i have to install any additional package to run the spark-similarity?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: What version of Mahout are you using? I think that Spark job execution supported was provided since Mahout 0.10.

Comment: The output of  'rpm -qa | grep mahout' is 'mahout-0.9+cdh5.7.0+29-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.79.el6.noarch'. So I guess Cloudera CDH5.7 comes with Mahout 0.9. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark support for Mahout came from [Mahout 0.10 release](http://mahout.apache.org/release-notes/Apache-Mahout-0.10.0-Release-Notes.pdf) while you are using 0.9 release. So this should explain why you get the `unknown program` error. I would suggest using a higher version of Mahout.

Comment: Cloudera only ships with 0.9+ however Mahout doesn't require complicated configs. Simply download Mahout and make sure `SPARK_HOME` is set properly in the env variables and it should work. (better yet- please call your CDH rep, and tell them you want Mahout 0.13.0)